# Ext js 4 editable grid + salesforce

Tags: extjs, salesforce

I need to save changes from an editable grid ext js in salesforce..

[ExtJS 4 > Row Editor Grid > How to Change "Update" Button Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750529/extjs-4-row-editor-grid-how-to-change-update-button-text)

This link above consist of row editing...When i click on the update button...I need to send the data to salesforce.. can you provide me with a simple example?

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to `edit` event for your row editing plugin: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing-event-edit